# Kubernetes pull images from private registry fails --> unknown field "imagePullPolicy"

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-registry, harbor

I'm trying to pull an image from my priavte harbor registry. In Kubernetes I created a secret first as explained in this documentation:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/

Then I tried to implement that into my deployment.yaml:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-k8s-test9
  namespace: k8s-test9
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx-k8s-test9
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx-k8s-test9
        image: my-registry.com/nginx-test/nginx:1.14.2
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: harborcred
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        volumeMounts:
          - name: webcontent
            mountPath: usr/share/nginx/html
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
      volumes:
        - name: webcontent
          configMap:
            name: webcontent
---
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: webcontent
  namespace: k8s-test9
  annotations:
    volume.alpha.kubernetes.io/storage-class: default
spec:
  accessModes: [ReadWriteOnce]
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
```

When I try to create the deployment I get the following error message:

```
error: error validating "deployment.yaml": error validating data: [ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.spec.imagePullSecrets[0]): unknown field "imagePullPolicy" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.LocalObjectReference, ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.spec.imagePullSecrets[0]): unknown field "ports" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.LocalObjectReference, ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.spec.imagePullSecrets[0]): unknown field "volumeMounts" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.LocalObjectReference]; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

I guess it's a yaml issue somehow but I don't know where it should be.

Answer (score 12):

And here is the solution:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-k8s-test9
  namespace: k8s-test9
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx-k8s-test9
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx-k8s-test9
        image: my-registry.com/nginx-test/nginx:1.14.2
        volumeMounts:
          - name: webcontent
            mountPath: usr/share/nginx/html
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
      volumes:
        - name: webcontent
          configMap:
            name: webcontent
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: harborcred-test
---
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: webcontent
  namespace: k8s-test9
  annotations:
    volume.alpha.kubernetes.io/storage-class: default
spec:
  accessModes: [ReadWriteOnce]
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
```

The imagePullSecrets section was not at the right place.

Answer (score 1):

can you chnage your config like this any give a try

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: webcontent
  namespace: k8s-test9
  annotations:
    volume.alpha.kubernetes.io/storage-class: default
spec:
  accessModes: [ReadWriteOnce]
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-k8s-test9
  namespace: k8s-test9
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx-k8s-test9
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx-k8s-test9
        image: my-registry.com/nginx-test/nginx:1.14.2
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: harborcred
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        volumeMounts:
          - name: webcontent
            mountPath: usr/share/nginx/html
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
      volumes:
        - name: webcontent
          configMap:
            name: webcontent
```

with `kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml` if it's not work try

```
kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml --validate=false
```

Comment: Validate = false will ignore the yaml sintax errors? I think it is better not using it.

Comment: The sintax is correct by the way. I checked using https://kubeyaml.com/

Comment: some time error occur cause of PVC section is after deployment in yaml file so it take time get pvc and deployment can't may connect

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this via creating & providing secret in pipeline and not editing the .yaml file

we had requirement was not to save secret in .yaml file as it was fetched from repo

step 1: create pipeline add a task
     Deploy to Kubernetes >> choose Action: Create Secret 
              - can find step how to create secrets

step 2: Then in any Task where you are pulling the .yaml file can use the secret by providing the secret name in ImagePullSecrets of Deploy to Kubernetes
[image: screenshot of imagepullsecret]